# Is there a Google API or anything that can get me access to the Google schema database?

Tags: javascript, google-api, schema, database-schema, schema.org

They have a database of all schema data that they've collected from websites. Like they know what concerts are going on around me. Is there any way that I can access that database? Whether it be through an API or some sort of script.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for [Knowledge Graph API](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/)